# Difference in mobile apps using vue.js and android

Tags: android, ios, vue.js

I am trying to develop a mobile application and ran into several examples that were made on Vue.js. I wanted to understand the difference in apps made out of android studio and something like vue.js. What are the few things I should keep in mind before deciding which to go forward with?

Comment: Android studio produces apps with a native interface.  Tools like View.js produce a web interface.  With the exeption of ReactNative, all JS UI frameworks are platform independent and render in a web view on mobile.  This gives you the advantage of reusing the UI on all platforms, at the cost of having access to native controls, native look-and-feel, and native APIs.

Comment: Can that still be used as an application on the phone or is it a mobile website now? Also, are there things which are preferred to be done in android rather than the web interface ?

Comment: take a look at https://nativescript-vue.org/ before believing reactNative is somehow special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android apps created with Android Studio (with native java or kotlin) is faster and reliable than the vue.js with NativeScript. You can't expect 1:1 performance and capability from nativescript-vue to native java or kotlin. It's because you have minimum 2 layers of abstraction when using nativescript-vue to native:

```
nativescript-vue -> nativescript -> native.
```

the performance will be impacted. And you should also beware of the nature of Android API, there are always changes between next API. So you'll have to wait for the next release of nativescript and nativescript-vue then your app development will be stalled until those frameworks updated.

You also need to consider the same condition with the iOS.

The problems of non-native is `low-performance` and `UI inconsistencies`.

And then you need to swallow a bitter pill: building and maintaining application created with JavaScript is hard.

If you really want to create a multiplatform app (Android and iOS), you can use **Flutter** instead of nativescript-vue.